# Tensorflow: Get color image data based on file names rather than directories

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-classification

I'm working on a color image classifier in Python using either an SVM or KNN classifier using the Tensorflow library.

The problem is, for various reasons, I'm not allowed to organize my training data into separate directories. For instance, my two classes are "Apples" and "Oranges" but all the image data is in one directory called "training", so I can only sort them by file names, like "Apples1", "Orange1".

This makes it difficult to use methods like `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` or even `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` because they look for directory names to determine classes.

Is there a good Tensorflow method for what I'm doing? If not, is there a good way to load and preprocess color image data to work with the Tensorflow library?

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** Haven't tested any of this in a complete training session. Use as a guideline rather than an exact solution.

**Option 1:** Build a `tf.data.Dataset` of your own.
There are many ways to do this. Easiest is to use a python generator. For more info, check out these resources: [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), [2](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control), [3](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators).

Here's a minimal example using generators.

Assuming directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── script.py
└── training
    ├── Apples1.jpg
    ├── Apples2.jpg
    ├── Apples3.jpg
    ├── Apples4.jpg
    ├── Oranges1.jpg
    ├── Oranges2.jpg
    ├── Oranges3.jpg
    └── Oranges4.jpg
```

The `script.py` contains the code below.

```
import os
import glob
import random
import tensorflow as tf

target_dir = os.path.realpath("./training")
file_paths = glob.glob(f"{target_dir}/*.jpg")

classes = ['apple', 'orange']
  
IMGW, IMGH, CH = 256, 256, 3
def data_generator(fpaths):
  fpath = random.choice(fpaths)
  class_index = [c in os.path.basename(fpath).lower() for c in classes]
  one_hot = tf.constant(class_index, dtype=tf.int32)
  image = tf.keras.utils.load_img(fpath, target_size=(IMGH, IMGW))
  input_arr = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(image)
  input_arr = tf.expand_dims(input_arr, 0) # add batch dim
  yield input_arr, one_hot

NUM_CLASSES = len(classes)
train_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
  data_generator,
  args=[file_paths],
  output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(IMGH, IMGW, CH)),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(NUM_CLASSES,))
  )
)

BATCH_SIZE = 64
train_dataset = train_generator.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(1)
```

Then `train_dataset` can be used in the `tf.keras.Model.fit()` to train. You can split `file_paths` to `train_file_paths` and `val_file_paths` to choose exactly which files you want to use for training vs validation and come up with a `val_dataset` using the same procedure.

**Option 2:** Nest the `training` directory into another directory.

The method `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` is a bit funky in my opinion, but I think you can still use it if you provide a list of integers for the `labels` argument that corresponds to the sorted list of image file paths in your `training` directory (according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory#args)).

Here's a minimal example.

Assuming you have a directory structure like this:

```
.
├── images
│   └── training
│       ├── Apples1.jpg
│       ├── Apples2.jpg
│       ├── Apples3.jpg
│       ├── Apples4.jpg
│       ├── Oranges1.jpg
│       ├── Oranges2.jpg
│       ├── Oranges3.jpg
│       └── Oranges4.jpg
└── script.py
```

Then `script.py` defined as below will create a `tf.data.Dataset` object like usual.

**Important:** Note the `target_dir`. It's not the `training` directory as we might expect, but one directory above.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

target_dir = os.path.realpath("./images")

for _, _, file_names in os.walk(target_dir):
  pass

file_names = sorted(file_names)
  
label_map = { 
  "apple": 0,
  "orange": 1,
}
labels = []
for fname in file_names:
  for k, v in label_map.items():
    if k in fname.lower():
      labels.append(v)
      print(f"Assigned label '{k}' to file '{fname}'")
      break

dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  target_dir,
  labels=labels,
)
```

Comment: Being one directory above creates an issue where it starts reading from the other directories that are in the same directory as my training data folder. Do you know if TensorFlow has a way of extracting image data from a directory without requiring being one directory above?

Comment: I guess you have two options: 1) nest the `training` folder inside another folder. If that's not possible for some reason, then 2) build a `tf.data.Dataset` which are documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data), with an example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control). If speed is not an issue, you could use a [generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators), which would be the easiest.

Comment: I can look at it tomorrow if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, it seems like my only option came to running 'tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(fiale_path)' in a for loop.

Comment: That should work. You can wrap it in a generator to create a `tf.data.Dataset`, which can be used the `fit()` function. I'll edit my answer to include another minimal example.